# Alternative for 'Creating a user session and starting an application in it from IIS using C#'

Tags: c#, asp.net, vba, ms-access, iis

An MS Access database is used to do processing on a server.
The current procedure is that people log in to the server using RDP and then run macros in the MDB-file.
These macros take sometimes days to execute.

A web application is developed that runs code in the MDB-file instead.
When MS Access shows a dialog like 'macros disabled, do you trust this file?' (due to server-updates) or any error that is not properly handled, the process does not exit but instead it keeps waiting for MS Access to complete.

Due to IIS this MS Access process is running in Session 0 where it cannot be shown to the user.
What I would like to do is be able to have the user connect with an RDP session, see the MS Access application and debug the VBA code.

Ideally I would create a new user session and run the MDB-application in it, but this seems to be impossible; Microsoft has disabled this because of security risks.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Any solution that gets the MS Access application to appear in the RDP session is welcome.

My current thinking is along this way: (but I would love to hear about a more convenient solution)

- Have an application running on startup of an interactive session, which communicates with the IIS proces and starts the MS Access application in the foreground when instructed to do so.
- If this application is not running (no RDP session is open) the web application gives an error message saying please connect using RDP before starting this job.

Comment: Bite the bullet, re-write to eliminate the access dependency entirely?

Comment: that's the plan for the coming years.

Comment: The time is now. Automating Office apps from services (including web services) has never been supported. Trying to bodge things to try and make it work is almost certainly going to require *more* engineering to accomplish than the rewrite

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say but this is a very large app. While we are rebuilding the app into something else we need a solution to keep things running.

Comment: Access is a Front End Application that connects to a database using the ACE driver.    When you double click on the MDB file it opens the Access Application installed on the PC and connects to the MDB data.  So you can connect to the data using the c# Net library Oledb.  You can also run Stored Procedures in the Database using Oledb.  I think this may solve your issue : http://bretstateham.com/configuring-iis-on-64bit-windows-7-to-work-with-the-access-2007-oledb-driver/

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the link. It doesnt solve my issue though. I am able to run MS Access from IIS, but I need to make it visible in an RDP session. Your solution is to treat it like a DB but I need to run the VBA code. It's about 15 years of development so not easy to rewrite.

Comment: Isn't the VBA code STORED PROCEDURES?  If you are able to get the Oledb to connect from a remote PC you can run the stored procedures (VBA).

Comment: What are these macro's doing? They can't be complicated - macro's are pretty limited in their operation. I suspect they are only running a series of action queries by the sound of it. @jdweng - no VBA is NOT stored procedures.

Comment: What do you mean by "debug vba code?" Can't you create unit tests for that? `disable warnings` `no error message boxes` should help you for now?

Comment: What the macros are doing: retrieving data from various databases and database files and parsing the data into different formats. Exporting to Excel, CSV and databases. Accessing various webservices and parsing the results back into tables and other data. And that several hundred times in different ways in subs and functions.

Comment: @krish KM the system is setup so that system updates a pushed automatically, some of them ruining MS Access functionality. When this happens end users have no clue of what is going on since they cannot see any messages coming out of MS Access.

Comment: use office interop from c#. you will have full access to Access Instance. where you can run Macros, public functions from C#. Besides `DoCmd.SetWarnings WarningsOn:=False` will throw errors rather than showing application related dialogboxes. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Minty: Read MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845861.aspx

Comment: @jdweng - read and digested... its a series of procedural statements, but so are most other programming languages... :/ ?

Comment: A stored procedure is VBA!!!!  Your comment that I was wrong is incorrect.

Comment: @krish KM I will try setting the warnings off, thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure if it catches the situation where macros are turned off in MS Access, or where the mdb-file is not trusted. Will report back when I tried this.

Comment: @krishKM - that may suppress some issues, but the thing is, using Office from services is just plain [not supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office). The recommendation for *decades* now has been to find alternatives to trying to automate Office from services, but the cleanest alternative that I'm aware of for Access macros is reimplement.

Comment: @MartiendeJong if the mdb is not trusted no vba code will be executed. However you can add trusted locations in the registry so any file within the location is automatically trusted. see here [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3cb49c3-de8d-41e4-b9ef-77a2f3efeab9/add-ms-access-trusted-location)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever OP is aware of those limitation and he did mention that they need the system running "until" they have a new system. So any solution proposed here would be a "temporary solution"

Comment: @krishKM - so, the current process of having people RDP in and use Access directly works. The "web server in front of Access" idea is/was a dead end that they should not have invested engineering time in. The "fix the dead end idea and conjure RDP sessions up" proposal that the question is looking for is also a dead end. The only sane approach is to continue with direct RDP/Access until such time as they can replace Access.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  I'm not here to argue with you about someone else's set up :) I just gave some ideas to hold the boiling plate sturdy. You might be right in terms of what the correct approach is. I leave that up to the OP to decide

Comment: @krishKM - I'm coming across quite blunt here in the comments. It's deliberate, but possibly not what the OP wants to hear - they've invested time building something that cannot work well. Yes, they want band-aids to make it work, but I don't feel I would be *helping* them if I gave them hope or helped them build something that is *slightly* less brittle but still prone to all kinds of issues. *Any* advice I give on SO (whether as comments or answers) I want to be 100% sure will help the user (and if I don't think they've picked the best approach, I make sure they know that too)

Comment: @Damien I appreciate your feedback and efforts, but as I stated before rewriting is not an option.

Comment: @krishKM I tried adding the mdb-file in trusted locations and disabling warnings but still an unknown event traps the MS Access application occasionally when it is run in Session 0 :'(. Because the Access instance is not visible I have no clue as to what is going on there and it does not occur when it is run in a user session.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback so far. I will try to have MS Access run in a user session using a background WCF app that communicates with the IIS webapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using a Windows Forms app that hosts itself so that it can be called from a webservice, in combination with the Interop Access library to start MS Access and the TestStack.White library to monitor what MS Access is doing.
End result is that the user can start the MS Access on a remote machine from a web application. Then when it runs properly the resulting message is returned to the web client. If a problem occurs the users gets a message that they have to login through an RDP session to view/debug MS Access. If the Forms app is not running (it is in the Startup folder for the user) a message is shown that an RDP session has to be started to be able to execute the MS Access file on the remote machine. Errors are also logged in the Forms application so the user has a log of what happened on the machine during previous runs.

DISCLAIMER: this code is in no way complete, it is a generalized extract of what I think are the important pieces of code. (the whole set of applications is huge) It should be possible to meld them together in something workable. If requested I will make a complete solution out of it and post that. I want to give someone else that may be looking for something similar something to start with.

Service host using TCP:

```
    var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService),
        new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9001"));

    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService),
        new NetTcpBinding(), "MyService");
    host.Open();
```

Then in the service I instantiate MS Access in new thread:

```
    Thread t = new Thread(() => { result = RunMdb(pathToMdbFile, "MyFunction", true); });
    t.Start();
```

The function that instantiates MS Access:

```
    private string RunMdb(string path, string functionToRun, bool visible)
    {
        string result;
        try
        {
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(newDir);

            // get the MS Access process, we need it later
            var before = Process.GetProcessesByName("MSACCESS");
            MsAccessApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application { Visible = visible };
            var after = Process.GetProcessesByName("MSACCESS");
            var process = after.Single(p => !before.Select(p1 => p1.Id).Contains(p.Id));
            MsAccessProc = process;

            MsAccessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(newDbPath, false);
            result = MsAccessApp.Run(functionToRun);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result = $"MS Access Error: {e.Message}";
            log.Log("MS Access Error:", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (IsFunctionRunning)
            {
                try
                {
                    MsAccessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase();
                }
                catch
                {
                    // ignored
                }
                try
                {
                    MsAccessApp.Quit(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveNone);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // ignored
                }
            }
        }
        MsAccessApp = null;
        MsAccessProc = null;
        IsFunctionRunning = false;
        return result;
    }
```

Then in the main thread I start polling MS Access with TestStack.White:

```
    result = TrackMsAccessPopups(log, result);

    private string TrackMsAccessPopups(ILogger log, string result)
    {
        while (IsFunctionRunning)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (MsAccessProc != null)
            {
                if (WhiteApplication == null)
                {
                    WhiteApplication = TestStack.White.Application.Attach(MsAccessProc);
                }
                log.Log(LogLevel.Info, "GetWindows.");
                WhiteWindows = WhiteApplication.GetWindows();
                log.Log(LogLevel.Info, "GetWindows done.");
                if (WhiteWindows.Count > (MsAccessApp.Visible ? 1 : 0))
                {
                    IsFunctionRunning= false;
                    log.Log(LogLevel.Error, "MS Access has created a popup.");
                    result = $"MS Access has created a popup. Log in on {Environment.MachineName} to view the message.";
                }
            }
        }
        WhiteApplication = null;
        return result;
    }
```

The resulting string is returned to the web application via a service callback.